# Adding self signed certificte to JRE keystore

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, eclipse-wtp

A couple of months back I added a **SSL cert in JRE's trustcacerts for avoiding not-a-valid-certificate issues.**

There I imported the self signed certificate to the following file

"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts"

**Question 1**

But now when I am trying to access to this file it's not available and instead when I go to

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib"`

I can find only one folder named **ext** and inside it a Zipped file named **QTJava**

Wonder what have happened to the files which were there under Java 6.

**Question 2.**

And also when I opened the Windows command Prompt in Admin mode and try to use keytool command in there it says

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts"

'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I Would like to know if someone knows a way to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: It seems fine on my system using the latest JRE, so I think your install is borked.

Q2: That's easy, add your JDK or JRE bin folder to the PATH environment variable. Normally something like `set PATH="%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin"` should do it (given that your `JAVA_HOME` variable points to your JDK or JRE installation folder).

Comment: Ya that's it. Q2 got sorted. I missed it. But not sure what exactly happened in Q1 problem and not really getting what you mean in the  answer for Q1 problem...

Comment: I meant that the installation may be corrupt. Or did you not install the JRE with your JDK? Reinstallation of the latest version may help. Note that 1.6 is as good as unsupported by now, try and migrate to 7! It should have the same folder structure as the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Q1 : Installation may be corrupt

Q2 : Add your `java/bin` to your PATH variable.

```
PATH="%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin"
```

For this to work, You need to have `JAVA_HOME` variable set in your environment pointing to your JDK installation directory

Comment: Hi yes thanks. Got missed the thing in the Q2 and it's alright. But do you know how I will have to set up the corrupted JRE6. I tried to find an option in Control pannel Apps Uninstall section to find a repair option. But found nothing like that....

Comment: You uninstall it or remove the directory manually. then, install the latest one. [Java 1.7.](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en)